# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I'm trying to create an html5 audio player. It's for a radio station, so I need the player to reload the source and start playing from 'currrentTime=0;' when the stream starts again. I get an error in the script though, and i'm not sure why?

My script is run

Error location: `if (player.id == 'paused') {` - I get the error: `' Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null`

HTML:

```
<audio onplay="checkState()" controls="controls" id="paused" src="http://rmceng.radiomaria.ca:8162/;stream.mp3"></audio>
```

My JS:

```
function checkState() {
var player = document.getElementById('player');
var psrc = 'http://rmceng.radiomaria.ca:8162/;stream.mp3';
if (player.id == 'paused') {
    player.currentTime = 0;
    player.src = psrc;
    player.load();
    player.play();
    document.getElementById('player').id = 'playing';
}
else {
    player.pause();
    player.src = "";
    document.getElementById('player').id = 'paused';
    }
}

window.onload = function(){
    checkState();
}
```

Comment: `var player = document.getElementById('player');` and  `id="paused"` somethings not right

Comment: ._. --- I'll quickly make that correction.

Comment: You keep changing the ID, so it no longer matches the second time you click. You should never need to change an ID.

Comment: How would you guys suggest I go about this then? -- This is my first attempt at Javascript. Slowly piecing things together by googling it haha

Comment: I'm guessing you could find the answer amongst the questions in the Related section to the right.... which should have come up when you typed your question title.

Comment: `id="player"` and `data-state="pause"` and just handle the states

Comment: Please don't change your question to a completely different question when you already have an answer for the previous one. You've basically made Falk's answer obsolete. Ask a new question with the new code and rollback your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no element in your markup that has the id player. So when you tell JS to getElementById, it can't find anything. So the value becomes 'null'. After that you call player.id - this is the same as trying to call the property id of an object that doesn't exist.

To fix:
Give your player the attribute `id="player"` or change the selection call. There are other ways to select elements.

```
document.getElementById(id_string)
document.getElementsByTagName(tag_name)
document.getElementsByClassName("class_values")
document.getElementsByName("name_value")
document.querySelector(css_selector)
document.querySelectorAll(css_selector)
```