# Uncaught TypeError AND automatic scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, events, mouseover, mouseout

i wrote something about mouse event, mouseout/over/enter/leave. i have two questions and problems. The first one is when you move your mouse immediately, rapidly from outside the browser screen into the box (its name is Parent). i got an error like mouse.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null at HTMLDivElement. (mouse.js:7).

i dont understand why and i don't know how could i solve it ?

the second one is , i am not sure maybe it is not problem, but automatic scroll down for textarea i wrote

every time under the event listener six times. how can i fix it ?

is there more clever way ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="html">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Javascript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="javascript.css">
    </head>
    

    <body id="body">
    

        <div id="parent"> Parent
            <div id="child">Child</div>
        </div>
            
            <textarea id="text"></textarea>
            <button id="clear">Clear</button>
        

        <script src="mouse.js"></script>


</body>
</html>

#parent {
  background:tomato;
  width:200px;
  height: 150px;
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
}

#child{ background: #FFDE99;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

textarea {
  min-height: 30vh;
  min-width: 90vh;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1.4rem;
}
#clear{
  margin-top: 1.4rem;
}


const parent = document.getElementById("parent");
const child = document.getElementById("child");
const text = document.getElementById("text");
const clear = document.getElementById("clear");

parent.addEventListener("mouseover" ,e => {
    text.innerHTML += `Type:${e.type}, Target:${e.target.id}, Related Target:${e.relatedTarget.id}\n`;
    text.scrollTop = text.scrollHeight;
});


parent.addEventListener("mouseout", e=> {
    text.innerHTML += `Type:${e.type}, Target:${e.target.id}, Related Target:${e.relatedTarget.id}\n`;
    text.scrollTop = text.scrollHeight;
});



parent.addEventListener("mouseenter" , e=> {
    text.innerHTML += `Type:${e.type}, Target:${e.target.id}, Related Target:${e.relatedTarget.id}\n`;
    text.scrollTop = text.scrollHeight;
})

child.addEventListener("mouseenter" , e=> {
    text.innerHTML += `Type:${e.type}, Target:${e.target.id}, Related Target:${e.relatedTarget.id}\n`;
    text.scrollTop = text.scrollHeight;
})

parent.addEventListener("mouseleave" , e => {
    text.innerHTML += `Type:${e.type}, Target:${e.target.id}, Related Target:${e.relatedTarget.id}\n`
    text.scrollTop = text.scrollHeight;
});

child.addEventListener("mouseleave" , e => {
    text.innerHTML += `Type:${e.type}, Target:${e.target.id}, Related Target:${e.relatedTarget.id}\n`
    text.scrollTop = text.scrollHeight;
});




// For Button

clear.addEventListener("click" , () =>{
    text.innerHTML = " ";
    
});
```

Comment: I think the error u get caused by HTML elements are not loaded just insert your JS code inside this : document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        // your code here
    });

Comment: But i put the script tag bottom of the html document.

Comment: Just try other the selection calls instead of getElementById(). Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40244416/10866402